# Powershell script for Power BI administration doesn't work in standard PS terminal

Tags: powershell, powerbi

When I run **Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount** in Powershell it pops up the Okta window for me to authenticate and that seems to work.  But when I run **Get-PowerBIWorkspace -All** I get this:

```
Get-PowerBIWorkspace : An error occurred while sending the request.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-PowerBIWorkspace -All
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (Microsoft.Power...owerBIWorkspace:GetPowerBIWorkspace) [Get-PowerBIWorkspace], HttpRequestException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : An error occurred while sending the request.,Microsoft.PowerBI.Commands.Workspaces.GetPowerBIWorkspace
```

I've done hours of googling and found nothing helpful.  I'm using version 1.0.896 of the Powershell modules from MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt.  I've tried using Fiddler but that didn't help me.  Is there a way to debug?  I've tried using "-Debug" and "-Verbose" but neither helped.

UPDATE: The full script I'm trying to use to list out all my workspaces/reports/datasets gets further when executed from the terminal within Visual Studio Code but I don't know why.  Eventually it fails too, saying "Operation returned an invalid status code 'TooManyRequests'."

Comment: Probably [Resolve-PowerBIError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoftpowerbimgmt.profile/resolve-powerbierror?view=powerbi-ps) could be useful in such cases.

Comment: @AndreyNikolov that did help, thanks! Today I'm able to run the scripts in VS Code because apparently I haven't hit the request limit, whatever that is. I still can't use the Powershell terminal by itself, but now I can see that it says "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."